# Why don't suggestion descriptions and hover info for TypeScript object properties in VS Code show the doc comment of the property's type?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

It's easiest to see the issue in the below image because the issue is about the popup box in VSCode that shows type info and comments. [image: type comment missing]

Here's the code, however, TS playground doesn't even show the comments that do work in VSCode so I'd avoid using it.

This issue also occurs for comments on template literal types.

```
/**
 * Special documented string to reuse this comment.
 */
type SpecialString = string;

interface Options {
  /** Foo */
  x: number;
  /** Bar */
  y: number;
  s: SpecialString;
}

const fn1 = (options: Options) => {
  console.log('foo');
};

/*
Desired behavior is how the comments appear in the popup when passing in
prop `x` and `x` but the comment is missing when passing in `s`.
*/
// fn1({})

// I don't want have to paste the same comment onto @param for both fn2 and 3
const fn2 = (special: SpecialString) => console.log(special);
const fn3 = (special: SpecialString, x: number) => console.log('foo');

/*
The 'Special' comment is missing when passing in the arg unless the comment
is pasted into an @param on both fn2 and fn3.
*/
// fn2();

interface SpecialStrings {
  /** Special comment */
  special: string;
}

const fn4 = (special: SpecialStrings['special']) => console.log(special);
/*
This also doesn't work to show the comment when passing in the arg.
*/
// fn4();
```

Comment: That's just how it works, it doesn't drill down to the next level of comments

Comment: Dang, it does for nested interfaces so I thought there would be a way for this to drill down.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very satisfying answer, but I'm pretty sure it's just like that. It could possibly be nice if TypeScript would show the doc comment for the type if the property of that type has no doc comment itself. You could [raise that as a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=Feature_request.md&title=). It's possible that this has already been asked for before, but I couldn't find an existing issue ticket with my search queries.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.